# Python regex replacement with str.replace. Pattern (wordhypenword) Replacement (wordspacehypenspaceword)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following regex pattern word-word, so

```
r'\w+\-\w+
```

I would like to replace it with

```
r'\w+\s\-\s\w+
```

**Example:**
I would like to change

```
hello-friends to hello - friends
```

**I have tried the following with no success**

```
df['mytextcolumn'].str.replace(r'(\\w+)(\\-)(\\w+)',r'(\\w+)(\\s)(\\-)(\\s)(\\w+)')
```

**also tried with re.sub**

```
re.sub(r'\\w+\\-\\w+',r'\\w+\\s\\-\\s\\w+','hello-friends') 

but I still get back hello-friends, not hello - friends
```

I also checked my regex with an online regex matcher for python, and it picks up the patterns correctly, so I am confused why I am unable to replace it within my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a new pattern in the replacement. Instead you can use 2 capture groups in the initial pattern, and use `\1 - \2` in the replacement.

You can capture `-` also in a group, but as it is a single character that you are literally matching you can also just use that in the replacement.

```
(\w+)-(\w+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilk4Or/1)

```
df['mytextcolumn'] = df['mytextcolumn'].str.replace(r'(\w+)-(\w+)',r'\1 - \2', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
      mytextcolumn
0  hello - friends
```